# webbrowser, opening chrome and internet explore for different url

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

```
url = 'http://www.google.org/'
chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

above will open chrome, which is what I want.

However if I change the url to `url = 'reddit` it will open internet explore instead. Why does it open different webbrowsers for different urls? And how can I make sure it opens in chrome for all urls?

Comment: What is `%s`supposed to be doing in your path string?

Comment: I followed another example, which used it. I do not know what it is for. Only that it'll give me a webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Comment: remove it and pass the actual path, also you should use `/` in the path string  or else prepend with an `r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> browser = webbrowser.get()
>>> browser.open('http://google.com')
True
>>> browser.open_new_tab('http://yahoo.com')
True
>>>
```

The `webbrowser.get()` call will get you a browser controller object. You can run `open`, `open_new` and `open_new_tab` on the controller object. This will ensure the commands are executed on the same browser instance you opened.

If you directly use `webbrowser.open()` - it will always open the link in the default browser, which in your case is Internet Explorer.

So to rewrite your code:

```
chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
chrome = webbrowser.get(chrome_path)
chrome.open('http://google.com')
chrome.open_new_tab('http://reddit.com')
```

Comment: I'm not trying to open 'http://reddit.com' but just 'reddit', if I type in 'reddit' in my google chrome it'll just behave as a google search, which is what I want

Comment: For that you need to use something like selenium. Even I am not sure if selenium has that feature but it's likely that it does.